# Multi classification problem with unique target labels

Tags: multiclass-classification

I would like to know if it is possible to predict values that are not repeated (unique) in my dataset.
Example: In this example let's say my features are [Price, velocity] and target variable is: [Car]. So, given two inputs (price, velocity) I want to predict the car brand. As you can see, Car will be always unique in this dataset.

So, I guess that I will have to encode my target variable, but this will always lead to unique numbers too: (Ford, 1 ), (Seat,2),....

```
Car       Price     Velocity

Ford      1000      200   
Seat      800       220
Ferrari   1234      300
Cupra     234       240
```

What approach would you recommend me to use? Is it possible with unique target labels?
The goal of the problem is:

Given two inputs :
`Velocity: 100 Price: 700`
Get probabilities of belonging to one class.
So the output would be:

```
Ford: 90%
Seat: 75%
Ferrari: 50%
Cupra: 40%
```

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. What do you mean by "unique"? It seems to me that you could have many rows with the same car, e.g. there could be multiple Ford cars with different prices. In case they are really unique, i.e. they appear only once as target, then the question is why do you want to build a classifier? A classifier is meant to find the target for cases never seen before, if it's exactly the same case a simple database is enough.

Comment: There are a lot of Ford vehicles in this world, so I think I’m misunderstanding what you’ve written, as you seem to indicate that you only have one Ford.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I want a classifier because I want to predict to which class belongs given the inputs. I am also thinking about the possibility of doing a regression problem, encoding my target with unique values and then mapping the result with the encoded class. Is that approach right?

Comment: This is just an example. I wrote cars for a simple example, but my dataset will be different and target variable will always be unique! ;)

Comment: It’s usually more helpful to describe what you really have and what you really want to do, rather than coming up with analogies.

Comment: Hi @Dave I clarified my goal in my post. I specified the desirable output

Comment: Now how are you getting probabilities that add up to more than $100\%?$

Comment: I guess in that case I would always take the one with max percentage. But I will see, maybe I will transform my data in some way. I just need to know what is the right approach and which model would fit this problem best.